# gmail SPF settings not working

Tags: email, gmail, spf

I'm trying to please gmail with my new server and I can't for the life of me figure out WTF they want.

I am sending mails **to** people with gmail accounts **from** my own SMTP server, I'm not a gmail user myself.

Here is the error I get:

> host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a]    said:
>   550-5.7.1 [2a01:488:66:1000:5c33:9242:0:1] Our system has detected
>   that this 550-5.7.1 message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines
>   regarding    PTR records 550-5.7.1 and authentication. Please review
>   550-5.7.1
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more
>   550
>      5.7.1 information. g66si22237116wmf.82 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA    command) Reporting-MTA: dns; flame.lemuria.org
>   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 253A341C05 X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822;
>   notifications@mightandfealty.com Arrival-Date: Mon,  7 Dec 2015
>   08:45:02 +0100 (CET)

And here is my SPF TXT record:

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:92.51.146.66 a:flame.lemuria.org include:lemuria.org +all
```

So as far as I can see, I have a proper A record for the sending server (flame.lemuria.org), there is a PTR reverse DNS pointing to this server under this name, but gmail is still whining. Of course trying to contact them results in zero answers.

Can someone tell me WTF they want to be happy?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is problem with the SPF record.

My guess is that your sending server has the IPv6 address: [2a01:488:66:1000:5c33:9242:0:1], and that address doesn't seem to have a PTR record. And Gmail (and others) does not like sending servers without PTR records. So if you add a PTR records for your IPv6 address, I think it will work.

A side note on your SPF record: Your ip4 and a mechanisms seem to be pointing to the same address. And your include record also contains most of the same addresses as in the main record. These redundant records may increase the risk of the receiving SPF validation failing due to DNS Lookup Limits.

Comment: You can also consider to disable IPv6 on the server or only bind your mail server to the IPv4 address. Because if you use IPv6 your SPF record should also contain information on this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes, they point to the same, I explicitly added the redundance because I was out of ideas what it doesn't like. I also don't use IPv6 which is why I don't have it configured.

Comment: You might not have selected to use IPv6, but your mail server does use the IPv6 address when sending to other IPv6 enabled mail-servers (hence the IPv6 address mentioned in the error). This is most likely caused by the  MailServer binding to all available addresses by default.